# Apostrophe displayed as &#39 in SP Dataviewer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I have a form being displayed in a page and data is getting stored in an SP List. When a user enters an apostrophe in a field, the same list item displays the apostrophe as ''' in the web part.

How should I get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your DVWP field, do you have disable-output-escaping="yes" added to the xslt reference for that item?  This will display apostrophe's and ampersands properly.

Answer (score 6):

It's rendering as HTML character code. Check out this article:

http://www.petestilgoe.com/2010/07/displaying-html-in-the-dataview-webpart-dvwp/

The article suggests changing your XSL to:

```
xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@MyHTMLFormattedColumn"
```